# example for populating spinner with Firebase realtime database

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, android-spinner

my database is arranged like this:

[image]

I want to get all the values from Students as a String List or any form of list and use it to populate a Spinner

**Tab2.java**

```
package com.example.shikh.first;

  import android.os.Bundle;
  import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
  import android.view.LayoutInflater;
  import android.view.View;
  import android.view.ViewGroup;
  import android.widget.Spinner;
  import android.widget.TextView;

  import com.firebase.ui.FirebaseListAdapter;
  import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
  import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;

  import java.util.ArrayList;


  public class practice extends AppCompatActivity {

//    private Spinner Category, SubCategory;
DatabaseReference reference;
Spinner areaSpinner;
ArrayList<String> areas = new ArrayList<String>();

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.tab2);


    reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReferenceFromUrl("https://practice-2f7d1.firebaseio.com");


    areaSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    DatabaseReference mref= reference.child("areas");


    FirebaseListAdapter<String> firebaseListAdapter = new FirebaseListAdapter<String>(this, EventCategories.class, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, mref) {


        @Override
        protected void populateView(View view, String s) {
            ((TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.text1)).setText(s.getName());
        }
    };
    areaSpinner.setAdapter(firebaseListAdapter);


}
```

}

Updated Code ^

Code shows error in populateView(View view,EventCategories s) method when i put EventCategories in place of string.

Comment: Try to do something by your own first. If you get problems, we'll help you.

Comment: Please sir have a look of my code

Answer (score 0):

You can use the FirebaseUi library, which uses a FirebaseListAdapter.
FirebaseListAdapter extends BaseAdapter, which implements the interface SpinnerAdapter.
So most of the code is already written...

Comment: i am doing it but it is giving me error in populateView() method

Answer (score 0):

First you should create a class with name 'Student'

```
public class Student {
String name;
String courseName;

public Student(String name, String courseName) {
    this.name = name;
    this.courseName = courseName;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getCourseName() {
    return courseName;
}

public void setCourseName(String courseName) {
    this.courseName = courseName;
}
public Map<String, Object> toMap() {
    HashMap<String, Object> result = new HashMap<>();
    result.put("name", name);
    result.put("courseName", courseName);
    return result;
}
```

}

then your database should look like this
[image]

You can get this structure of database by using push() and updateChildren() methods when saving to the database. You can see docs [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write).
Now come to the FirebaseListAdapter

```
FirebaseListAdapter<Student> firebaseListAdapter = new FirebaseListAdapter<Student>(this, Student.class, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, reference) {
    @Override
    protected void populateView(View view, Student s) {
      ((TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.text1)).setText(s.getName());
    }
};
```

Here is the FirebaseRecyclerAdapter [docs](https://firebaseui.com/docs/android/com/firebase/ui/FirebaseListAdapter.html#populateView(View,%20T)).

Comment: i want to populate spinner

Comment: in populateView() method if pass the object of student class as parameter it is giving the error "FirebaseListAdapter should implement abstract populateView() method.

Comment: please show your code snippet where this error occurs.

Comment: hloooooo anyone there?

Comment: what is EventCategories.class?

Comment: its a model class same as student.java

Comment: I've shown initialization of firebaseListAdapter inn my answer. You've to replace Student with your own model class. In your updated code still you are using String in FirebaseListAdapter<String> and in the override method as well.